# Window-based Flow Control with HornetQ/STOMP

Tags: hornetq, stomp, flow-control

I'm wondering how to pull a single message from queue when using HornetQ/STOMP.

According to this http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/flow-control.html#d0e4023 , it seems possible to achieve it with **consumer-window-size** in the case of JMS api for HornetQ, which is called as *window-base flow control*.

But, some posts on the internet suggest it's not possible with **STOMP** client:

- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/160106?tstart=0
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/156748?start=15&tstart=0
- https://developer.jboss.org/message/912048#912048

It seems to me that the 'consumer-window-size' thing is a server-side setting, which can be globally applied to all connections. Then, if I'm ok with having all connections non-buffered (consumer-window-size=0), is it possible to enforce it even for STOMP clients by configuring in on the server side? Or it's not possible at all with the current Hornet STOMP support to have non-buffered connections for STOMP clients as the posts above seem to suggest? (i.e. non-buffered connection won't work for STOMP clients even if I set it on the server-side?)

In contrast, ActiveMQ/STOMP seems to support this by making it configurable per connection through 'prefetchSize' described here: http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html